# Not getting response from mongoose model.find() query

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, promise

I am trying to fetch all records from my mongo db using model and schema. I am able to connect to db. And when I run query I dont get any response.

**routes.js**

```
import express from 'express';
var router = express.Router();
import mongoose from 'mongoose';
const db = 'mongodb://localhost:27017/dbname';
import {contacts} from '../models/model.js';

// exports this js file
export { router }

//connect to mongodb

mongoose.createConnection(db, { useNewUrlParser: true , useUnifiedTopology: true }, (err, res) => {
       if(err) {
           console.error("Error: "+ err);
       }
       else {
           console.log('connected to mongodb');
       }
})


router.get('/check', (req, res)=> {
    res.send('in roues');
});
```

//mongo db calls

```
router.get('/contacts', (req, res) => {
    console.log('getting contacts');
   let promise = contacts.find({}).exec();
   console.log(promise);
   promise.then(function(err, contacts) {
       console.log('in func');
       if(contacts) {
           console.log('data received');
           console.log(contacts);
           res.send('data received');
       }
       else {
           console.log('doc not found');
       }
   })
})
```

**model.js**

```
    import mongoose from 'mongoose';
    const schema = mongoose.Schema;

    const contactSchema = new schema({
            name: String,
            details: [
                {
                    text: String,
                    icon: String
                }
            ]
        });

    let contacts = mongoose.model('contacts', contactSchema);

export {contacts}
```

**Console output:**
  (node:27440) ExperimentalWarning: The ESM module loader is experimental.
    server started
    connected to mongodb
    getting contacts
    Promise {  }

Comment: The Promise returned by `contacts.find().exec()` does not accept the same arguments as the nodeback in `contacts.find(..., nodeback)` In the case of the Promise, a successfully delivered value will travel down the Promise's success path or an error down its error path. The branching has been done for you. Therefore, `contacts.find({}).exec().then(successHandler).catch(errorHandler);`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be cause of not catching the error. use **then catch**   or **try catch with async await.**

```
  router.get('/contacts', (req, res) => {
  console.log('getting contacts');
  contacts.find({})
    .then(contacts=> {
      console.log(contacts)
    })
    .catch(error=>{
     console.log(error.mmessage)
    }
```

i have used es6 arrow function.
You can also follow **try catch with async await**

```
  router.get('/contacts', async(req, res) => {
    try{
     console.log('getting contacts');
     const contacts = await contacts.find({})
       console.log(contacts)
    }
    .catch(error){
     console.log(error.mmessage)
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

you must handle the error case with the catch function, see this link

https://medium.com/@lucymarmitchell/using-then-catch-finally-to-handle-errors-in-javascript-promises-6de92bce3afc

Answer (score 0):

.then(...) only takes one parameter, which is the resolved response.

So instead of
promise.then(function(err, contacts) { ... }); use
promise.then(function(contacts) { ... });